# How can I have more year reputation than total reputation?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I happened to look up my reputation this morning, and it shows this for the "Year" tab:

[image]

Note that my reputation for the year is 100 points higher than my total reputation, even though I have only been around for 8 months, so all the months were I could gain any reputation and where I collected total reputation fall into this year. How can that be? I'd also have expected that total reputation has to be as large or larger than reputation from any time period.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've [offered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/75095/groody-the-hobgoblin?tab=bounties&sort=offered) bounties totalling 200 reputation. That's reputation you've earned and is thus counted in your yearly gain.

The reputation leagues also [don't count the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81456/294691). This means that, while your total reputation will accurately reflect your current reputation, the yearly count has a -100 from not counting the association bonus, but a +200 from counting your offered bounties as rep earned, which leaves a +100 discrepancy.

Comment: Do you know anything else that causes this kind of discrepancy? [One particular user](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/77769/annaag) has a difference of 81, which wouldn't be possible with bounties and association bonuses alone. Here's [a user](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/65261/pepijn) with a differences of -74 and [another user](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/74994/hikari) with 13

Comment: IIRC downvotes on answers and posts that were deleted three months after posting (which means the user keeps the rep from the post) can also cause discrepancies.